# Javascript Cant Find Variable Callback

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a node.js app and I'm running the javascript code from my app.js and the function runs correctly and all carbines are passed through the function but my callback is never returned.

The script runs, and everything comes out how it should with the console.log, but the callback isn't callback is never called when i run the function with the error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: callback
```

here is the code.

```
    var username;
    var password;

    function getBalance(username,password,callback) {
    console.log("info that main.js received: ",username,password);
    try {
      var Spooky = require('spooky');
    } catch (e) {
      var Spooky = require('../lib/spooky');
    }




    var spooky = new Spooky({
      child: {
          transport: 'http',
          "ssl-protocol": "any"
      },
      casper: {
          logLevel: 'debug',
          verbose: true
      }
    }, function(err) {
      if (err) {
          e = new Error('Failed to initialize SpookyJS');
          e.details = err;
          throw e;
      }

      spooky.start('https://bank.simple.com/signin');

      spooky.then([{
    auth: username+"_"+password
    }, function () {
    this.evaluate(function (auth) {
    var info = auth.split("_");
    username = info[0];
    password = info[1];

      document.getElementById("login_username").value = username;
              document.getElementById("login_password").value = password;
    }, {
      auth:auth
    });

    }]);
      spooky.thenClick('#signin-btn', function() {
          this.emit('notifForTitleChange', 'Hello, from ' + this.evaluate(function() {


              return document.title;
          }));
      });

      spooky.thenOpen('https://bank.simple.com/account/balances');

      spooky.then([{
    },function() {
              var pre = document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0];
    callback(pre.innerHTML);
      }]);


      spooky.run();

    });



    spooky.on('error', function(e, stack) {
      console.error(e);

      if (stack) {
          console.log(stack);
      }
    });


    spooky.on('console', function(line) {
      console.log(line);
    });


    spooky.on('valueChanged', function(greeting) {
      console.log(greeting);
    });

    spooky.on('gotInfo', function(balance) {
      console.log(balance);


//Note: this callback isn't getting called    :


    callback(balance);
    });


    spooky.on('log', function(log) {
      if (log.space === 'remote') {
          console.log(log.message.replace(/ \- .*/, ''));
      }
    });
    };



    module.exports.getBalance = getBalance;
```

Comment: some sample code would be helpful. In general I would give notification center a try.

Comment: You could use `if`. Just set it to be `if` (something happens) execute code. Or use `if` to check for the end result of the thing that you want to make sure happens.

Comment: I would like to remove a view when there are no touches on the screen 
so when touches count is 0 i want to do something

Comment: When there are no touches after what? After the user touches the view and then removes all touches?

Comment: Look up `touchesEnded`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have lots of views on the screen that all receive touches, and you want to detect when there are no touches left on any of them, you can use a subclass of `UIApplication`.

When the user touches the screen, the system tells your app about it by sending the `sendEvent:` message to your app's `UIApplication` object.  In `sendEvent:`, the application figures out which window should get the touch, and delivers the touch to that window.

So you can look at every touch event by subclassing `UIApplication` and overriding `sendEvent:`.  Let's make a subclass of `UIApplication` that posts a notification when the last touch ends or is cancelled.

First, we'll create a new class named `MyApplication`.  In `MyApplication.h`, we declare a constant for the name of the notification we want to post:

```
extern NSString *const LastTouchEndedNotification;

@interface MyApplication : UIApplication

@end
```

In `MyApplication.m`, we'll define the notification name variable:

```
#import "MyApplication.h"

NSString *const LastTouchEndedNotification = @"LastTouchEnded";
```

We need a function that looks at a `UIEvent` and returns `YES` if the event represents the end (or cancellation) of the last touch:

```
static BOOL lastTouchEndedInEvent(UIEvent *event) {
    NSSet *touches = event.allTouches;
    if (touches.count == 0)
        return NO;
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        switch (touch.phase) {
            case UITouchPhaseBegan:
            case UITouchPhaseMoved:
            case UITouchPhaseStationary:
                return NO;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    // There was at least one touch, and all touches either Ended or Cancelled.
    return YES;
}
```

Now we can implement `MyApplication`.  In `sendEvent:`, we call `super` to deliver the event as usual, and then we see if the event represents the end of the last touch.  If so, we post the notification:

```
@implementation MyApplication

- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super sendEvent:event];
    if (lastTouchEndedInEvent(event)) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:LastTouchEndedNotification object:self];
        NSLog(@"all touches ended");
    }
}

@end
```

We need to modify `main.m` to use our new class, by passing the class name as the third argument of `UIApplicationMain`:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv,
            NSStringFromClass([MyApplication class]),
            NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Finally, to respond to the notification, you add an object - probably a view controller - as an observer of the notification.  Example:

```
#import "MyApplication.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(lastTouchDidEnd:) name:LastTouchEndedNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)lastTouchDidEnd:(NSNotification *)note {
    [self.someView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: THATS EXACTLY WHAT I WANTED! I LOVE YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Target/action, delegate, notification, method. They all do something when they are called. Timer, performSelector. They can control the when.

So, you can use a timer to trigger some event to happen, you just need to decide when to start the timer and what it does.

Comment: Please leave a comment if you down vote. Though I guess I should have commented the question about how poor it is...